# UART communication using the Atlys board with a computer running a Terminal program

Tags: fpga, xilinx, xilinx-ise, xilinx-edk

I want to connect an hyper terminal to an Atlys Spartan-6 xc6slx45 FPGA,I follow a tutorial which I found on youtube.But when I press a button the screen of hyper terminal still clear.The board is well connected to the PC.

Comment: did you set correct the baud rate  ? send the youtube video also

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to connect a terminal to an fpga board](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29257948/how-to-connect-a-terminal-to-an-fpga-board)

Comment: @gaby:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tcB7px6P8j8.